# Why is flask setting this header to 'Connection: close'?

Tags: python, flask

Here is my flask code in a file called `main.py` -- I am trying to get a simple server-sent-event stream going:

```py
import time
from flask import Flask, Response
from werkzeug.serving import WSGIRequestHandler

app = Flask(__name__)


def counter():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = i+1
        yield "data: " + str(i) + "\n\n"
        time.sleep(1)


@app.route('/stream')
def send_message():
    return Response(
        counter(),
        mimetype='text/event-stream',
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=55'
        }
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    WSGIRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
    app.run(port=5001)
```

When I run this app with `python main.py` and open it up in a browser, the response headers read BOTH `Connection: keep-alive` AND `Connection: close`.

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I get flask to only use the keep-alive header?

Answer (score 0):

I have just hit the same issue (Flask 2.0.3 with Python 3.6.8) also while implementing a server-sent-event (SSE) stream.

Flask uses the Werkzeug library (version 2.0.3 in my case).

In Werkzeug, its response writing function 'write' (defined within WSGIRequestHandler.run_wsgi in serving.py) conditionally writes the 'Connection: close' header after writing all of the headers from the response object.

This happens unless any one of the following conditions are true:

1. the 'Content-Length' header is present in the response
2. the request method was 'HEAD'
3. the response status code is <200
4. the response status code is 204
5. the response status code is 304

Importantly it is does not check to see if the response object already has a 'Connection' header e.g. if you have added your own 'Connection' header, as you have.

This is why Flask is appending the 'Connection: close' header.

Note that for this SSE use-case I think its correct that all of the 5 conditions above are false. In particular the status code should be 200, the request method 'GET', and the 'Content-Length' header unspecified. Therefore I think this is a bug in Werkzeug and will raise a Issue against it.